# How do I show a UITableView within a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am a new Swift programmer and I am currently working on a **very** simple to-do-list application. The catch is that I want to display a not-to-do list as well. Additionally, I am attempting to do this all through code.

I want the user to be able to scroll horizontally between 2 CollectionViewCells, that each have a TableView within them displaying a 'To Do List' and a 'Not To Do List'.

So far I have a ViewController that creates a UICollectionView that has 2 custom cells that each fills up the window, so the user can scroll between them.

I am working on the "Not To Do List" cell, and I am trying to display a TableView within it, but I am having difficulty displaying it.

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
...
collectionView.register(ToDoListCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: toDoListCellid)
collectionView.register(NotToDoListCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: notToDoListCellid)
...
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if (indexPath.item == 0) {
        let toDoCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: toDoListCellid, for: indexPath)
        return toDoCell
    }
    else {
        let notToDoCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: notToDoListCellid, for: indexPath)
        return notToDoCell
    }
}



class NotToDoListCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var ntdlArray = ["Play Video Games", "Eat out", "Watch Netflix"]
let ntdlCell = "ntdlCell"

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}



extension NotToDoListCell: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return ntdlArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ntdlCell, for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = ntdlArray[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
}
```

I would expect that the table view would show up with 3 rows of text containing: "Play Video Games", "Eat Out", and "Watch Netflix" but all I see is an orange screen (from when I set the background color of the NotToDoListCell to orange). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need add a tableview to your cell.  Are you defining the cell in a storyboard or NIB file?  Or do you want to do everything programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this completely programmatically without using a nib/xib file , you need to make a table view inside a collectionview cell , you can do something like this:

```
class NotToDoListCell: UICollectionViewCell {

   lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
         let tblView = UITableView()
         tblView.delegate = self
         tblView.dataSource = self
         tblView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         return tblView
   }()

var ntdlArray = ["Play Video Games", "Eat out", "Watch Netflix"]
let ntdlCell = "ntdlCell"


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ntdlCell) 
    setupTableView()

}
func setupTableView() {

    addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottom.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true 


}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}



extension NotToDoListCell: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return ntdlArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ntdlCell, for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = ntdlArray[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about this last night and you have confirmed my answer! Appreciate it a bunch!

Comment: @MikeH if this is the right answer please accept it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need add the `tableView` in your `NotToDoListCell` as outlet from your xib file and add in the `awakeFromNib` method `self.tableView.dataSource = self`

```
class NotToDoListCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var ntdlArray = ["Play Video Games", "Eat out", "Watch Netflix"]
let ntdlCell = "ntdlCell"

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}

override func awakeFromNib(){
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}


extension NotToDoListCell: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return ntdlArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ntdlCell, for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = ntdlArray[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
}
```