# Adding tableview inside multiple collectionviewcells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, swift4

I ran into a problem with my app. I have successfully made a CollectionView with 5 cells, scrolling horizontally. In each cell I want to have a tableview that will display separate data received from an Arduino. But I can't get the tableview to display at all.

**ALL** the code in this view has been made programmatically.

There is one thread in particular who gave me hope in finding this out by myself. I tried the accepted answer here: [How do I show a UITableView within a UICollectionViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767502/how-do-i-show-a-uitableview-within-a-uicollectionviewcell) 
But, I still didn't work.

Since I am inexperienced in general with swift, and even more so with designing in code I suspect there is some constraints issues, since I have experienced that before.

**Here is my collectionview code:**

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

let cellId = "cellId"

 // Returns how many items in one sections
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    // displays different colors in all the 5 sections
    let colors: [UIColor] = [.blue, .green, .gray, .red, .orange]
    cell.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}

//Determines the size for each cell
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width , height: view.frame.height - 50 )
}
//Minimize the line spacing between the sections ... return 0 (no spacing)
func  collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
    }
```

**And then there is the tableview Code:**

```
class ReceivedCell: UICollectionViewCell {


lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tv = UITableView()
    tv.delegate = self
    tv.dataSource = self
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return tv
}()


let tableViewCell = "tableViewCell"
var array = ["test", "test1", "test2"]

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: tableViewCell)
    setupTableView()
    //setupViews()

}

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("Init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
extension ReceivedCell: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableViewCell, for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.item]


    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
```

}

Please feel free to ask questions, if anything is unclear! I am so close to finishing my app, I got all rest of code ready to go into the tableview, I just gotta be able to display it. Thanks a lot guys!

**EDIT**

[I want to have a tableview in every sections 1 - 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSxcc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add some codes so that the following vcs will work as you want.

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

let cellId = "cellId"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.register(ReceivedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


// Returns how many items in one sections
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ReceivedCell
    print(cell.contentView.frame)
    // displays different colors in all the 5 sections
    let colors: [UIColor] = [.blue, .green, .gray, .red, .orange]
    cell.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}

//Determines the size for each cell
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width , height: view.frame.height - 50 )
}
//Minimize the line spacing between the sections ... return 0 (no spacing)
func  collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}


 }
  class ReceivedCell: UICollectionViewCell {


lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tv = UITableView()
    tv.delegate = self
    tv.dataSource = self
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return tv
}()


let tableViewCell = "tableViewCell"
var array = ["test", "test1", "test2"]

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20),
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor,constant:  -20),
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor,constant: 20),
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor,constant: -20),
        ])
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: tableViewCell)
    tableView.reloadData()

   // setupTableView()
    //setupViews()

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("Init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}

extension ReceivedCell: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableViewCell, for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.item]


        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }}
```